# How to browse and choose a generic file with MvvmCross

Tags: android, windows-store-apps, cross-platform, mvvmcross, filechooser

I'm writing a cross platform app (Store App and Android) with MvvmCross. In his helpfull webcasts, Stuart Lodge shows how to use Picture Chooser Plugin to select an image from the device library. But, what about other types of files (text, xml and so on)? With a IMvxFileStore object it's possible to read text and binary files, but how to choose them?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a ready made solution for this that I know of - and 2 key mobile platforms really won't provide this (winphone and ios don't really do filepickers)

However, if you wanted to implement your own file picker interface on droid, wpf and winstore then it should be relatively easy to do:

- define an interface in your core project
- implement the interface in wpf and winstore using common dialogs
- implement the picker in droid using simple directory listing code (or some 3rd party component)
- register the components during app setup

There's an n+1 video on injecting services and plugins which may help.